# Textarea maximum character acceptance

Tags: html, textarea

What's the maximum number of characters a `<textarea>` element will accept in a standard HTML form?

1000 or more?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has limit or default maxlength value. At least the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html#textarea.attrs.maxlength) doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `<textarea>` is a field that qualifies as type `LONG` from [W3 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html#textarea.attrs.maxlength), and in turn, it seems `LONG` supports 64,000 characters [here](http://www.itworld.com/answers/topic/software/question/how-many-characters-can-long-text-field-contain-access-2013).